# Verifica se em um grupo de valores, existe um valor x mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo um select que retorna alguns dados do banco, mas preciso que esse select retorne os valores somente quando em um grupo de valores, exista o valor x

```
SELECT pessoas.id AS ID,
pessoas.nom_pessoa AS nome,
pessoas.cod_sexo_pes AS sexo,
YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(pessoas.dta_nasc_pes))) AS idade,
CASE WHEN pessoas.cod_cert_civ_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS RN,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_rg_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS RG,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_nis_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS NIS,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_cpf_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS CPF,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_cart_trab_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS CP,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_tit_eleit_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS Titulo,
familia_domicilio.nom_local_fam AS bairro
FROM pessoas
INNER JOIN familia_domicilio ON familia_domicilio.id = pessoas.cod_familia
WHERE
familia_domicilio.nom_local_fam = 'AGUAS ESPRAIADAS'
AND YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(pessoas.dta_nasc_pes))) BETWEEN     '1' AND '100';
```

Neste caso, eu gostaria que o select me retornasse os valores selecionados, somente se existisse pelo menos um valor "Não" entre as colunas pessoas.cod_cert_civ_pes/ pessoas.num_rg_pes /pessoas.num_nis_pes / pessoas.num_cpf_pes / pessoas.num_cart_trab_pes / pessoas.num_tit_eleit_pes.

Comment: Não é só usar o operador OR?

Comment: Em qual parte do código usaria o OR?

Comment: ...WHERE (pessoas.num_nis_pes = 'Não' OR pessoas.num_cpf_pes='Nao' OR... e assim por diante ....

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado meu caro

Comment: @user46464 se o AND do comentário acima resolveu, é o caso de usar IN pra simplificar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode acrescentar mais um AND entre () por seus valores separados por OR da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT pessoas.id AS ID,
pessoas.nom_pessoa AS nome,
pessoas.cod_sexo_pes AS sexo,
YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(pessoas.dta_nasc_pes))) AS idade,
CASE WHEN pessoas.cod_cert_civ_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS RN,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_rg_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS RG,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_nis_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS NIS,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_cpf_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS CPF,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_cart_trab_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS CP,
CASE WHEN pessoas.num_tit_eleit_pes !='' THEN '--' ELSE 'Não' end AS Titulo,
familia_domicilio.nom_local_fam AS bairro
FROM pessoas
INNER JOIN familia_domicilio ON familia_domicilio.id = pessoas.cod_familia
WHERE
familia_domicilio.nom_local_fam = 'AGUAS ESPRAIADAS'
AND YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(pessoas.dta_nasc_pes))) BETWEEN     '1' AND '100'
and(pessoas.cod_cert_civ_pes !='' or pessoas.num_rg_pes !=''  or  pessoas.num_nis_pes !='' or pessoas.num_cpf_pes !=''
or  pessoas.num_cart_trab_pes !='' or pessoas.num_tit_eleit_pes !='')
```

Answer (score 2):

Para testar se um valor está entre vários, basta o operador `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE "Não" IN ( campo1, campo2, campo3 )
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7260/1)**.

Dados:

```
(1, 'Sim', 'Sim', 'Sim'),
(2, 'Não', 'Sim', 'Sim'),
(3, 'Sim', 'Sim', 'Não'),
(4, 'Sim', 'Não', 'Sim')
```

Resultado:

```
id  campo1  campo2  campo3
 2  Não     Sim     Sim
 3  Sim     Sim     Não
 4  Sim     Não     Sim
```

Comment: Não tinha pensado nessa logica ....